# How do i sum up different rows values base on certain condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the `FutureSales` field by summing up all future Sales when the Month in the table is more than the row itself.

```
Year    Month   Month_No    Sales   FutureSales 
2015    Jan     1           5       106 
2015    Feb     2           15      101 
2015    Mar     3           21      86
2015    Apr     4           4       65
2015    May     5           10      61
2015    Jun     6           51      51
```

However, this seems to be more complex than i imagine. Does anyone here have any quick fix on how this can be achieved?

Comment: what mean by "when the Month in the table is more than the row itself" ?

Comment: What im trying to say is that if at month 2, any row that have month >= 2 will get summed into the future sales

Answer (score 1):

You can write condition on `where` clause.

```
select sum( some_data )
  from your_table
 where _here_you_limit_the_rows_to_be_processed_
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, the main concern is summing the value across different rows

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a table called **table1**

which table format are:

```
Year    Month   Month_No    Sales
2015    Jan     1           5      
2015    Feb     2           15       
2015    Mar     3           21      
2015    Apr     4           4       
2015    May     5           10 
2015    Jun     6           51
```

Try this code,

```
select a.Year, a.Month, a.Month_no, a.Sales, 
(select sum(Sales) from table1 where Month_No >= a.Month_no and Year = a.Year) as FutureSales
from table1 a
```